# Visudo Command Not Working on Sudo User

Tags: 14.04, sudo, visudo

I recently bought a vps and I have am fairly new to using ubuntu on it since I have always used shared hosting.

I have created a sudoer user and it worked perfectly fine yesterday except when I edited the `ssh/ssh_config` file to disable password authentication, it did not work, and I decided to work on it tomorrow.

I stopped my server, and when I booted it up today, and tried the command `sudo visudo /etc/ssh/ssh_config` it would just put display

```
usage: visudo [-chqsV] [-f sudoers] [-x file]
```

rather than opening up the file.

I know it is something wrong about my usage but I can't seem to figure it out, I did the same exact command yesterday and it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: `visudo` is a command for editing the `sudoers` configuration file itself, **not** for editing other configuration files with administrative privileges

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command to edit a file using `sudo` is `sudoedit`:

```
sudoedit /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Equivalently, you can also do:

```
sudo -e /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

`visudo`, as already noted, is specifically meant for editing `sudoers` files. It performs syntax checking assuming the file is a `sudoers` file. You don't want to use it to edit other files.

Answer (score 0):

Use nano, visudo won't work for anything other than the sudoers config.